# How to make etckeeper use the right value for git author & email with apt-get

Tags: configuration, git, etc

I'm using git with etckeeper.

When I use sudo git to commit changes in `/etc/`, GIT_AUTHOR_NAME & GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL from my env are used (as intended).

When I use `sudo apt-get` and changes are auto-committed, the local username@host is used instead.

Why the change in behavior and how can I make `sudo apt-get` use the ENV vars?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this is fixed in etckeeper 1.5](https://git.joeyh.name/index.cgi/etckeeper.git/commit/?id=a890ac4a2ca4c9580b4a2e3a0c84f0ba249867dc). It happened in `/etc/etckeeper/commit.d/50vcs-commit`:

```sh
if [ "$VCS" = git ] && [ -d .git ]; then
  if [ -n "$USER" ]; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$USER"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$USER@$hostname"
  fi
  if [ -n "$logfile" ]; then
    git commit $GIT_COMMIT_OPTIONS -F "$logfile"
  else
    git commit $GIT_COMMIT_OPTIONS
  fi
[ ... ]
```